# Folder/source code sharing options between linux guest and Windows host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, windows-10, file-sharing

Host is Windows 10,
guest is Ubuntu server, running under Virtual Box.

Desired feature is to be able to share a folder containing source code between these too.
Basically I want to be able to edit the source code in Windows (vscode), but run the code within Linux.

I am aware of the "shared folders" feature from Virtual Box, however it does have a few flaws, this is why I am looking for alternatives. One of the problems with VM shared folders is that by default creating symlinks is disabled, so every time I run `npm install` or `yarn`, I get E_PROTO errors. To fix this I have to either run them with --no-bin-links, which is not an option because I am not the only one working on the code... or force symlinks in vbox with `VBoxManage setextradata...` and run the vm as administrator.
Another flaw is that npm/yarn create millions of files, something I have no control over because it is not my source code and I cannot decide what to install or not. And this slows things down a lot.

I was thinking to try the sftp option, which has its own disadvantages, but before I do that, maybe someone here has a better solution

Comment: There are numerous off-topic elements to this, but on my environment, I use mklink in the guest to create a folder linked to the host shared folder. Done.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In the guest, the source code folder is already a symlink to the shared folder mounted in `media`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use SMB or NFS?
Both of them are windows features and can be set up easily.
You can mount SMB or NFS folder on Linux VM.

Comment: After some more research, SMB seems to do the job. thanks for the idea